# How to solve fourth order pde similar to biharmonic equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a fourth order pde similar to the biharmonic equation

$
0=\frac{\partial ^4}{\partial x^4}u(x,y)+Q\frac{\partial ^4}{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}u(x,y)+\frac{\partial ^4}{\partial y^4}u(x,y)
$

Where Q is a constant. The boundary condition are the following,

$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,y)=0\quad \quad \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u(x,y)=0 \quad \textit{and} \quad \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}u(x,y)=0
$

while the boundary is a rectangle.

So far neither Fourier series nor separation of variables seems to work on this one and I'm no expert to the topic.

Comment: Do you have boundary conditions?

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question accordingly. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Do you have some boundary conditions on $u$ itself?

Comment: no, only on the derivatives.

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,y)=0$ , $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u(x,y)=0$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}u(x,y)=0$ are not belonging to the boundary conditions since they are already restricted the form of $u(x,y)$ should be.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not get what you mean with this?